# Windows-10 auto-correct, how to use it with the keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, autocorrect

I want to try using the Windows 10 auto-correct with my keyboard, not with the mouse. I enabled it in the  `Typing -> Hardware keyboard -> Show text suggestions as I type` configuration.

I can see it showing options as I type:

[image]

But how do I select one of the options without having to reach for the mouse and click on it? Can I do it purely with the keyboard?

I've tried finding documentation on this feature in the Windows site without success.

I've also tried all sorts of key combinations like `ctrl+space`, `shift+space`, `tab+space`, `arrow keys`, `alt+arrows` (although that takes my hand away from the home row). All with no success.

Answer (score 10):

You can use **Up Arrow** key to select the suggested word then **Right arrow** key to navigate through the suggestions.

I verified it on Windows 10 Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134

Comment: i can't get it to work.. i mean i can select the misspelled word the way you suggested, however when I select it it simply appends the new word to the misspelling.. surely this cannot be 'intended behaviour'. I have no idea what i'm doing wrong

Comment: I've just been trying it. I had the same issue as you - where it added the correction onto the end of the typo - but then as I was trying it again repeatedly, it kept replacing the word correctly. Whilst Up Arrow, Right Arrow does work - it's far too cumbersome.

Comment: The described solution works for me on Windows 11 23H2 Build 22631.2861 as well.
Additionally, pressing `Space` or `Enter` accepts the currently selected suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

As I know, you cannot get auto correct with the hardware keyboard. Auto usually tends to show up when you get suggestions for whatever you are typing.

But hey, that does not mean you cannot use auto correct. To be clear the windows keyboard gives suggestions for the entries you make.

The fall back here is, auto correct is perfect with a touch screen PC and so if your PC is not a touch screen you will not enjoy the auto correct/suggestions much or probably at all.

If you are using windows 10, type on-screen keyboard in the `search area`.

Once the suggestion comes up, just click on the keyboard and it should open up. Now you have the auto correct keyboard/suggestions. Use your fingers to punch the keys on the screen if it's a touchscreen PC, if not then your mouse will do all the punching.

*Click the below image to see the screen-capture video.
*The auto correct/suggestions did not respond well to the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do is.

While the suggested words are present press the up arrow, the right to select the correct suggeestion and then spacebar to accept so kind of like this.

Type the word in **step #1**:

1. **wring**
2. <kbd>⬆</kbd>
3. <kbd>➡</kbd> (Step optional to select the 2nd and 3rd suggestion instead)
4. <kbd>Space</kbd> (To accept the suggestion)